# How to combine rows after a JOIN where duplicate first columns occur, but differing information in the other columns

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem with the way the results are outputted to a HTML table after combining the data of two sql tables.

Table 1 appears as below

```
+-------------+------------+---------+
| StationName |  Address   | Manager |
+-------------+------------+---------+
| Station1    | London     | John    |
| Station2    | Liverpool  | Phil    |
| Station3    | Manchester | Mike    |
+-------------+------------+---------+
```

Table 2 appears as below

```
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
| StationName | Score1 | Score2 | Score3 |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Station1    | Pass   |        |        |
| Station1    |        | Fail   |        |
| Station1    |        |        | Pass   |
| Station2    | Fail   |        |        |
| Station2    |        | Pass   |        |
| Station2    |        |        | Pass   |
| Station3    | Pass   |        |        |
| Station3    |        | Pass   |        |
| Station3    |        |        | Pass   |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I would like the combined data to output as shown in this table

```
+-------------+------------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| StationName |  Address   | Manager | Score1 | Score2 | Score3 |
+-------------+------------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| Station1    | London     | John    | Pass   | Fail   | Pass   |
| Station2    | Liverpool  | Phil    | Fail   | Pass   | Pass   |
| Station3    | Manchester | Mike    | Pass   | Pass   | Pass   |
+-------------+------------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
```

However it appears like this.

```
+-------------+------------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| StationName |  Address   | Manager | Score1 | Score2 | Score3 |
+-------------+------------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| Station1    | London     | John    | Pass   |        |        |
| Station1    | London     | John    |        | Fail   |        |
| Station1    | London     | John    |        |        | Pass   |
| Station2    | Liverpool  | Phil    | Fail   |        |        |
| Station2    | Liverpool  | Phil    |        | Pass   |        |
| Station2    | Liverpool  | Phil    |        |        | Pass   |
| Station3    | Manchester | Mike    | Pass   |        |        |
| Station3    | Manchester | Mike    |        | Pass   |        |
| Station3    | Manchester | Mike    |        |        | Pass   |
+-------------+------------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
```

My query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.stationName = table2.stationName
```

I guess I am looking for a way of using something similar to GROUP BY, but without it aggregating the data.

Someone suggested pivot tables, though from what I have read of those, they are useful for calculations - I am interested in combining text data into the columns from multiple tables where the common link is the station name.

Can anyone please advise on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A GROUP BY is the way to go. Try this:

```
SELECT stationname, address, manager,
MIN(score1) as score1,
MIN(score2) as score2,
MIN(score3) as score3
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.stationName = table2.stationName
GROUP BY stationname, address, manager
```

Comment: I got there in the end, but this works great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

kbball's answer probably will fix your issue. However, good database design eliminates a lot of issues and can make coding very easy.

I think you need to redesign the data. Table2 should probably have just one score column and then another column that tells you which score each row is. If you do keep the three score columns, the code that populates that table should put all three scores on the same row.

Comment: The problem I have found with GROUP BY is that it only displays one of the results of the columns for each row. Having just one score column is not really a solution; I have simplified this for sake of explanation of my problem. Ultimately I need to be able to pull in a lot of other data from different tables and have it display in one row next to each station name.